# Hash and (MAC) based signatures using zk-SNARK

Tags: hash, signature, zero-knowledge-proofs, mac, snarks

I was wondering if we could use any general symmetric key MAC, a collision resistant hash $H$ and zk-SNARK (or any general NIZK scheme) to construct a signature scheme. I have a MAC key $k$, which is also my private key, and the public key is $h = H(k)$. As a signature for the message is $(mac = MAC_k(m),\pi)$  where $\pi$ refers to a proof using SNARK circuit which takes public input $m,h,mac$ and private input (witness) $k$ and calculates $mac' = MAC_k (m), h' =H(k)$ and outputs $1$ iff $mac=mac'$ and $h'=h$ .

Looks like we need to be extra careful if the MAC above is an HMAC with the same hash function $H$ since it uses actual $Key' = H(Key)$ if the $Key$ longer than block size,other than that are there other issues with it?
Is it secure?

If it is not secure can anyone give a reason why? Way to recover key or forge a signature would be even better.

Answer (score 3):

This is a valid paradigm for building a signature scheme, although a secure commitment scheme should be used to commit to $k$ instead of just using $H(k)$ as the public key. This type of construction was published by Bellare and Goldwasser at CRYPTO'89; see [New Paradigms for Digital Signatures and Message Authentication Based on Non-Interactive Zero Knowledge Proofs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwii-dqau5HvAhXCxoUKHYc3CPYQFjABegQIAhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fcontent%2Fpdf%2F10.1007%2F0-387-34805-0_19.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3vbKZZG9LF7x3iw3GJuws6). Formally, they use a NIZK, as you stated.